Tub drain won't stay open after overflow replacement, but not always
The overflow plumbing in our jetted tub was replaced by a plumber after it started to leak through the ceiling below. The leak has not reoccurred, but since the repair, the drain controls don't work correctly.
The tub has a cable-driven drain control with a rotary knob; this diagram was with some installation paperwork left by the previous owner. When you rotate the knob, it opens the drain, and the drain is meant to stay open while the tub empties.

Since the overflow was replaced, the drain will not stay open on its own when the tub is full and the rotary knob is turned. You have to hold the knob in the open position for some time until the water has dropped below a level where it won't force the drain stopper closed.
Confusingly, it doesn't do this every time. If I fill the tub up to the max, run the jets etc and try to drain the tub immediately, the drain will stay open and behave as expected. If the tub is used for the duration of a normal bath, with the jets running off and on, water being drained and added, then this issue comes up when trying to drain the tub at the end. The only difference I can think of is that somehow the emptying behavior changes when there's already a lot of water in the drain plumbing?
The only other symptom after the overflow repair is that the drain often makes repetitive thunking or knocking sounds, and on occasion a kind of shrill noise like there's a lot of air coming through somewhere. These also aren't consistent, but I can't remember them occurring previously.
I have had the plumbing who did the original work back 3 times to try to identify the issue (including the same exact plumber twice) and all they've done is adjust the drain stopper height, including adding tape to the screw to keep it from loosening. I had a jetted tub specialist in to look at it as well and he did the same thing, also to no success.
Any suggestions on what to look for or what to suggest a plumber look for would be extremely appreciated.
